# How do I add printed statements into a dictionary in the form of a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to solve a homework problem that involves adding booleans into a new dictionary, along with a classification system. It may be that I don't understand the problem clearly, but, I am really struggling to format the results the way the test cases are displayed.

Here is the problem description:

> Problem 1 (20 points):
>
> Write a function, called number_classify, that accepts a maximum positive integer
>   and returns a dictionary that maps integers to tuples of boolean and integer values.
>
> ## Test Case #1: classify all numbers from 2 up to 6.
>
> For every number from 2 up to and including the maximum, the function adds the number to the dictionary and assigns it a tuple formatted as (is_prime, classification), where:
>
> `is_prime` is `True` if the number is prime (divisible only by itself and one) and `False` if it is not.
>
> `Classification` is 0 if the number is perfect, -1 if the number is deficient, or 1
>   if the number is abundant (see section 2.1.6 and 2.1.7 for a definition of
>   these terms and a partial solution to determine a number's classification).
>
> It is recommended, but not required, that you simplify this problem by creating two
>   helper functions.  The first takes an integer as input and returns True if the number
>   is prime and False otherwise. The second should implement the solution indicated for
>   the classification field (2.1.7) and return the appropriate value (0, 1, or -1).

...and here is the current code that I have:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if (num <= 1):
        return False
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i == 0):
            return False
    return True


def number_solution(num):
    divisor = 1
    sum_of_divisors = 0
    while divisor < num:
        if num % divisor == 0:
            sum_of_divisors = sum_of_divisors + divisor
            divisor = divisor + 1

    if number == sum_of_divisors:
        return 0
    elif number < sum_of_divisors:
        return 1
    elif number > sum_of_divisors:
        return -1


def number_classify(max_int):
    a_dict = {}

    for x in range():
        if is_prime(max_int):
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")

    return a_dict
```

How can I format the output as shown in the test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete your number_classify with:

```
def number_classify(max_int): 
    a_dict = {}

    for x in range(1, max_int+1):  # loops 1, 2 ... max_int
      a_dict[x] = (is_prime(x), number_solution(x)) # desired tuple

    return a_dict
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could I ask you a follow up question? I made the helper function number_ solution so that it would classify the numbers for me as 0, 1, or -1. Could I call that instead of number_classify for the tuple?

Comment: @toeknee--actually you pointed out a 'typo' in my code.  I meant to call number_solution.  I corrected my post.  Thanks.

Comment: I thought so! But, I wanted to make sure. I am just learning how to code now! Thank you so much again! you have been such a great help!